# Python mock patch instance method and check call arguments

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I am using Mock (http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library with Python 2.7. I have a main function that calls a few other functions that I am trying to test.

The other functions that it calls are other instance methods (so for example, `def _other_function(self, a, b)`.

I am calling my main function, and I have the other functions that it calls patched. I just added `autospec=True` to the patch. When I check for call arguments however, it shows a `self` argument (as expected):

```
python2.7> _other_function_mock.call_args_list
[call(<some.module.class.method object at 0x9acab90>, 1, 2)]
```

Before setting `autospec=True`, it would only show that arguments that I actually passed (1 and 2). Since now the call args show a reference to `self`, I can't just call `mock_object.assert_any_call(1, 2)`. I will need to pick out the arguments from `mock_object.call_args_list` and compare.

Is there a way to still call `mock.assert_any_call` without having to pick out the arguments manually to check that the arguments passed are correct?

Or is there something better in general that I can do to patch instance methods?

Answer (score 12):

Essentially there are two ways to play around `self` reference for `autospec=True` patches.

1. Use [`mock.ANY`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.ANY) to ignore the first argument
2. Patch object by `patch.object` instead of patching the static method reference.

Anyway *2* cannot be used in all cases sometimes you cannot have the object instance in test method context; moreover that way often make test less clear and more complicated. I always prefer to use *1* in my tests:

```
@patch("my_module.MyClass.my_method", autospec=True)
def test_my_test(self, mock_my_method):
    my_module.MyClass().my_method(1,2)
    mock_my_method.assert_any_call(mock.ANY, 1, 2)
```